# CVS: see log of last n commits

Tags: cvs, revision-control

How can I see a list of the last n commits to a CVS repository?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
cvs history -x AMR | tail ...
```

But this requires a `history` file on CVS server [(info page)](http://docs.freebsd.org/info/cvs/cvs.info.history_file.html), which may not be present.